# In Django, how can properly implement a custom mail back end?

Tags: python, django

My goal is simply to print out the subject line and recipients whenever an email is sent from Django,

EDIT: and then send the email to its destination.

So I have implemented a custom backend like this:

```
from django.core.mail.backends.base import BaseEmailBackend

class EmailBackend(BaseEmailBackend):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        for message in email_messages:
            recipients = '; '.join(message.to)
            print(f'{recipients} {message.subject}')
        return super().send_messages(email_messages)
```

However when I try to send an email with this back end the log says:

```
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]: Internal Server Error: /secure/rest/djauth/users/
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     response = get_response(request)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     raise exc
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     self.perform_create(serializer)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 144, in perform_create
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "./emailbackend/email_passthrough_logging.py", line 17, in send_messages
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     return super().send_messages(email_messages)
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:   File "/opt/theapp/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/base.py", line 59, in send_messages
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]:     raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseEmailBackend must override send_messages() method')
Mar 15 08:44:19 ip-172-26-4-21 uwsgi[190188]: NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseEmailBackend must override send_messages() method
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Why do you not use the [Console backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend) if you just want to print?

Comment: I have edited to clarify that I wish to send the emails, not just print.

Comment: I think you want to inherit from the [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend) instead. `BaseEmailBackend` does not do the email sending, etc. It's simply as the name suggests the base class of the email backends.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are calling the ***`super()`*** method!!!

When you call the **`return super().send_messages(email_messages)`**, Python will call the [**`BaseEmailBackend().send_messages()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/50ef9dfac21499ff6c46c2f6a33103e40b60cd4e/django/core/mail/backends/base.py#L59) method and and thus an error will be raised.

---

So, what is the proper way?

Django uses the [**`smtp.EmailBackend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#email-backend) as the default mail backend and overriding the method of the same might help you

```
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend


class CustomEmailBackend(EmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        for message in email_messages:
            recipients = '; '.join(message.to)
            print(f'{recipients} {message.subject}')
        return super().send_messages(email_messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you call the ***super()***

if you check the **send_messages()** method from **django.core.mail.backends.base.BaseEmailBackend** class you get this  :

```
 def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        """
        Send one or more EmailMessage objects and return the number of email
        messages sent.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseEmailBackend must override send_messages() method')
```

this is where your error comming from

to use **BaseEmailBackend** you have to implement your own email backend check this repo of an example of how using BaseEmailBackend ([link](https://gist.github.com/mjrulesamrat/616db1c5b260287b8c0e5eb221830906))

or inherit **smtp.EmailBackend** that already inherit the **base.BaseEmailBackend**

and overit the **send_message** method